# Too many interesting questions are closed

Tags: discussion, closing, close-reasons, context

In my opinion you close far too many interesting questions as being off-topic and requiring additional context.  If someone is asking a question, he or she must consider it relevant.  If it is about mathematics, it is very likely relevant to other community members.  Why not let the community ask for additional context if it feels that that would be pertinent?

Comment: They can and do. The closure of the question with the explanation of a lack of context is the bare minimum of asking for that context.

Comment: We've been through this many many many many many times before. Unlikely anything new will be said this time around. Better to search meta for previous discussions and read through the give-and-take.

Comment: Sorry... what do you believe voting to close for lack of context is, if not a request for additional context by those community members? Poster can add that additional context either before the five closure votes are cast, or after (and request re-opening). Closure votes for lack of context *is* the community asking for additional context because it feels it would b epertinent.

Comment: Could you give examples of the type you are referring too ? Because what is interesting to you may not be to others

Comment: Also worth mentioning 'being interesting' isn't a primary factor for consideration, given how subjective it is.  But typically, interesting questions are usually interesting because one can easily find compelling context for them.

Answer (score -8):

I think that the OP is saying that interesting questions are ‘foreclosed’ (by this I mean closed so that no further answers can be provided) too early. This could be a relevant view about the procedure to foreclose the question and could be a support, for, in future to relax the system so that foreclosure is either not done too rapidly or that a more relaxed view is taken of the questions allowed to progress e.g. maths related is presumably set in stone, but how much ‘off topic’ or how advanced / relevant / previously asked could be adjusted.
In the end it might be a ‘freedom to enquire’ vs a purity argument. Presumably those who find a question or answer uninteresting could just move on…

Comment: Closure of questions that should be closed, **should** be early. There is no point preventing answers to a question if insufficient quality after those answers are posted, and there is no incentive to fix the question when it already has an answer. The entire complaint is based on an ignorance of the purpose of closure, and likely of Stack Exchange in general.

Comment: My opinion is that if a question has generated interest, it should not be closed unless perhaps the OP has refused to provide additional requested information.

Comment: @RichardHevener It sounds a little bit like you are confusing closure with removal.  In cases where cooperation and work comes from the poster, closure is a temporary protection. It only has lasting consequences when the user abandons the question.  At one time it was considered 'on-hold' but it didn't stick (I don't recall for what reason we gave up on that.)

Comment: Close quickly, delete slowly.  Closure is not a punishment.  It is an opportunity to slow down the process so that an asker can add relevant details.  All too often, questions with no context are answered by folk who assume that they know the context, only to have their answers rendered irrelevant after the question is edited.  Quick closure gives *everyone* a chance to step back and figure out what is really needed.